# Meaning of 空港から空港へ

Tags: particles

A sentence from JapanesePod101, with the official translation.

> サンダルは、空港から空港へ空の旅をするときに便利だ。
>   Sandals are convenient for traveling through airports.

To me 空港から空港へ sounds like "moving from one airport to another", but does this particular phrase simply mean walking through an airport as the translation suggests?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are correct, but there is a lot that is omitted due to implication here.  It's saying that when you travel, going from airport to airport, the implication is that you frequently remove your shoes, so sandals are convenient for doing so.  Without that assumption, there's no other real benefit that sandals provide over shoes.

20+, 30+, 40+ years ago, this sentence would not have carried the same meaning when airport security was not as strict, and people would not have been taking their shoes on and off as much.

---

**EDIT**:  From the comments, it seems that Japanese people frequently remove their shoes during a flight just as they do in their homes.  So the implication of often removing shoes is likely more related to this than to airport security measures.

Comment: I read the sentence very differently myself.  You probably do not know that quite a few Japanese people like to take their shoes off in airplains just like when they are at home.  AND this was even more common 20+, 30+, 40+ years ago than it is now.  I really do not see it having anything to do with "walking through an airport" or "security".  I know it is too late when OP is already satisfied with this answer but I needed to throw in my 2 cents where fit as a Japanese-speaker.

Comment: @TokyoNagoya OPが回答をacceptした後のスレでも、遠慮なく回答してください。acceptは変更可能ですので。

Comment: Before reading this answer, I read the sentence in the same way as Tokyo Nagoya did.  However, after reading it, I think that both interpretations are possible.  Given that the author chose to write 空港から空港へ空の旅をする instead of just 空の旅をする, I am leaning toward the airport-security interpretation, although I do not view it as a decisive factor.